# Use of argparse in Snakemake script

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, argparse, snakemake

Is it possible to pass custom command line arguments to `snakemake` scripts? I have tried, but executing Snakefile with `argparse` results in error `snakemake: error: unrecognized arguments: -zz`. Below is an example script.

```
import argparse

def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Compares Illumina and 10x VCFs using RTG vcfeval')

    # required main arguments
    parser.add_argument('-zz', metavar='--filename', dest='fn', help='Filename', required=True)

    # parse arguments
    args = parser.parse_args()

    fn = args.fn
    return fn

fn = get_args()

rule test_1:
    input:
        fn + "/example.txt"
    shell:
        "echo Using file {input}"
```

Comment: How are you invoking this script?  Normally I'd expect to see: `python your_script.py -zz afilename`.

Comment: Found the solution. Allows it via `--config`. [Source](http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/faq.html#is-it-possible-to-pass-variable-values-to-the-workflow-via-the-command-line)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Passing arguments from command line is [possible using `--config`](http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/faq.html#is-it-possible-to-pass-variable-values-to-the-workflow-via-the-command-line). For example:

`snakemake --config zz="filename"`

In snakefile script, this can be used in this way:

```
rule test_1:
    input:
        fn + config['zz']
    shell:
        "echo Using file {input}"
```

[See the doc](http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/configuration.html#configuration) for more info.