# Snakemake live user input

Tags: snakemake

I have an a bunch of R scripts that follow one another and I wanted to connect them using Snakemake. But I’m running in a problem.

One of my R scripts shows two images and asks a user’s input on how many cluster there are present. The R function for this is [readline]

This query on how many clusters is asked but directly after the next line of code is run. Without an opportunity  to input a number. the rest of the program crashes, since trying to calculate (empty number) of clusters doesn’t really work. Is there a way around this. By getting the values via a function/rule from Snakemake

or is there a other way to work around this issue?

Comment: This [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45972471/3998252) using `--config` might be relevant.

Comment: @ManavalanGajapathy This is not exactly what i'm looking for. The comandline input is asked in the midel of an R script that is called by snakemake.

But it did help make things easier somewhere else :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my testing with snakemake `v5.8.2` in MacOS, this is not a snakemake issue. Example setup below works without any problem.

File *test.R*

```r
cat("What's your name? ")
x <- readLines(file("stdin"),1)
print(x)
```

File *Snakefile*

```py
rule all:
    input:
        "a.txt",
        "b.txt"

rule test_rule:
    output:
        "{sample}.txt"
    shell:
        "Rscript test.R; touch {output}"
```

Executing them with command `snakemake -p` behaves as expected. That is, it asks for user input and then touch output file.

I used function `readLines` in R script, but this example shows that error you are facing is likely not a snakemake issue.